# GitHub Actions yml Syntax

Tags: github, github-actions

I am new to GitHub actions and for a few days I have been trying to set up a simple action workflow. I tried searching everywhere about the errors, went through some action workflow syntax documentation by GitHub but still I am not able to figure out anything.

I am trying to use this action template: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/jelastic-github-actions

I just copied and pasted the sample code given in the repo and filled in necessary values but there is always at least one error that keeps popping up.

What is wrong with the yml syntax below (this is exact sample code):

```
- name: Run GetEnv command
  uses: abhisek91/github-actions-jelastic@master
  with:
    jelastic_url: app.mycloud.by
    jelastic_username: ${{ secrets.JELASTIC_USERNAME }}
    jelastic_password: ${{ secrets.JELASTIC_TOKEN }}
    task: environment/control/getenvs
```

Github is showing me `Invalid type found: object was expected but an array was found` for the above code and I don't know what it means.

Comment: Where's the rest of it? The root of a GitHub Actions YAML file must be an object, what you've posted appears to be an entry from [`jobs.<job_id>.steps`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsteps) without any of the rest of the workflow structure.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you so much for your comment. There were several things I was missing. I assumed that as the complete syntax. I fixed it now. Thank you again.

Comment: seems bugged, try [this one](https://github.com/DovnarAlexander/github-actions-jelastic) instead